# Mathematical model of support vector machine

Tags: python, svm, mathematical-optimization

Could anyone please refer me to any tutorial or reference that shows how to code and solve the SVM mathematical model using Python? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure. This is the one that I have bookmarked long back.

https://medium.com/@ankitnitjsr13/math-behind-support-vector-machine-svm-5e7376d0ee4d

Comment: Thanks Vijeth 
But what I am looking for is how to build the mathematical model of SVM using Python or Cplex. In my research, I am looking at SVM as an optimization problem. So, I made some modifications on the obj function and some constraints. The next step that I am trying to learn now is to build the model on Python \

Comment: The above blog explained SVM properly. Just apply those mathematics as codes and your custom svm will work. You can google for implementation of SVM in you are in a , you'll find githubs where it is done